# Calling methods from other files in python results in executing the entire python file

Tags: python

I am new to python programming. I have written sample code as flows.

temp.py

```
p = 'Tushar'
print(p)

class Basics:

    def __init__(self, name, phNum):
        self.name = name
        self.phNum = phNum

    def getString(self):
        temp = self.name+' '+str(self.phNum)
        print(type(temp))
        return temp

bs = Basics("tushar", 9620207652)
x = bs.getString()

print(x)

def isBlue(isBlue):
    if(isBlue):
        print('Boolean true')
        x = 'true'
    else:
        print('Boolean false')
        x = 'false'
    return x

tus = isBlue(True)
if(tus != None):
    str = bs.getString().split(' ',1)
    print(str[0])
    print(str[1])
```

Hello.py

```
from temp import Basics

class Check:

    def __init__(self):
        print('Check obj')

    def createName(self, firstName, lastName):
        str = firstName + ' ' + lastName
        return str

emp = Check()
completeName = emp.createName('Tushar', 'Banne')
print(completeName)

b = Basics('Tushar', 98765432)
val = b.getString
print("Val is {}".format(val))
```

I am running Hello.py file and getting the below output.

> Tushar
>
> class 'str'
>
> tushar 9620207652
>
> Boolean true
>
> class 'str'
>
> tushar 9620207652
>
> Check obj
>
> Tushar Banne
>
> Val is (bound method Basics.getString of 0x0000024ECCCB5B70

The questions that I have are as follows

1. Why is the entire temp.py getting executed?
2. How to execute only getString method.
3. Why is it that when I use parenthesis after getString, it fails.
4. Why is the `val` printing object reference?
5. Am I following the correct standards of python coding?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour, whole file needs to be executed as python is a dynamic language and you can change stuff anywhere in the module. If `temp.py` imports another file, that whole file will be executed too and so on.

Comment: Tagged duplicate to a question which has several good answers. Also you wanna read [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the entire temp.py getting executed?

That's how it works. Importing a module means essentially executing it.

> How to execute only getString method.

In order to do so, the code in `temp.py` has to be changed in a way that it is only executed when the module is run at highest level ("as the `__main__` module") instead of imported.

You do that this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = 'Tushar'
    print(p)

class Basics:

    def __init__(self, name, phNum):
        self.name = name
        self.phNum = phNum

    def getString(self):
        temp = self.name+' '+str(self.phNum)
        print(type(temp))
        return temp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bs = Basics("tushar", 9620207652)
    x = bs.getString()
    print(x)

def isBlue(isBlue):
    if(isBlue):
        print('Boolean true')
        x = 'true'
    else:
        print('Boolean false')
        x = 'false'
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tus = isBlue(True)
    if(tus != None):
        str = bs.getString().split(' ',1)
        print(str[0])
        print(str[1])
```

> Why is it that when I use parenthesis after getString, it fails.

I don't see it fail in your question.

> Why is the val printing object reference?

Because you asked it to. Referring to a method or function means seeing it as an object and printing its string representation. If you call it (with the `()` behind), you perform a function call.

Answer (score 1):

First, check this out [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

When you are importing a python file, all of the code is executed.

3. What do you mean fails, what is the error?
4. `val = b.getString` means that now val references the method getString, that's why it is printed.
5. No, read the link above, also, python uses snake_case, not camelCase, so call the method get_string, not getString.  (this obviously doesn't changes thte